# Is it a good programming practice to use Class.cast() method instead of (Class) casting?

Tags: java

Is it a good programming practice to use Class.cast() method instead of (Class) casting?

What are the pros and cons of the two approaches. What are pitfalls of the both of them?

Answer (score 2):

I think (class) casting is easier to understand rather than the Class.cast(). When using an IDE for java like eclipse, IDE would prefer generating the (class) casting, that way it is a faster approach in coding.